# Can I invert the hessian using row operations like this?

Tags: linear-algebra, hessian-matrix, gaussian-elimination

I put my derivations in this image here: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am just using gaussian elimination by integrating all row elements. Is this acceptable?

With this approach, we only need to invert the hessian once for any nxn matrix. Then we can plug in our values.

Comment: Say what? What does inverse mean to you? Cute pun with (anti)derivations, though.

Comment: @TedShifrin What do you mean? If I continue with this derivation, I'd expect inv(H)*H = Identity which is just the definition

Comment: P.S. Do you not know a pat formula for the inverse of a matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: No, you are confusing the inverse of a matrix with the $D^{-1}$ you may have seen in a differential equations course.

Comment: Try a simple example. Say $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 + x_2^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Not sure what a "pat formula" is that you're referring to. And no, I am not confusing the matrix with the differential operator. Not sure why you'd assume that

Comment: @TedShifrin Since the integral can be treated like a linear operator, why can I not just multiply this differential operator to an entire row like a number?

Comment: Just stop and do the example I gave you.

Answer (score 2):

No, integration is not a row operation in the elimination.

Added some details:
To compute the inverse, the procedures is to multiply some matrices of row operations on both sides, if H is invertible, then the left block can be reduced to the identity matrix I.

$$H | I$$
$$E_n E_{n-1} \cdots E_1 H | E_n E_{n-1} \cdots E_1I$$
$$I|E_n E_{n-1} \cdots E_1$$

If the left block: $E_n E_{n-1} \cdots E_1 H = I$.
Then, $H^{-1} = E_n E_{n-1} \cdots E_1 $.

---

You may go back to how you solve system of equations originally,
Try solving this, g should be left parts of the inverse,

$
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{11} & f_{12}\\
f_{21} & f_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1\\
g_2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1 f_{11} + g_2 f_{12}\\
g_1 f_{21} + g_2  f_{22}
\end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Then try to integrate the first row, note that $g_1$ and $g_2$ is not just a constant, it is a function of (x,y), that's why you cant integrate both rows like that.

Moreover, when you integrate on both rows, the constants c are arbitrary, the values of two rows are not the same, and you still need to eliminate the constatnt c to get the identity matrix.

Comment: How exactly does the row swap work if you interpret the gauss-jordan elimination as multiplying by matrices?

Comment: Since the integral can be treated like a linear operator, why can I not just multiply this differential operator to an entire row like a number?

Comment: Try compute EH, it is just multify 2 times the 2nd row to the 1st row,
E=$(\begin{matrix}
1 & 2\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix})$,

H=$(\begin{matrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{matrix})$

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you mean, you combine a lot of things together, 
gaussian elimination, system of equations, solving ode/pdf, let me edit my answer.